# Redshift - Pulling the right most value from cell

Tags: sql, split, amazon-redshift

I have a columns with list of fruit names. I am trying to extract the right most value from the cell. Cell can have one value or n values. In which case, I am expecting to pull the last value.

Given below sample shows the actual value (col name: name_of_fruits) and the expected value (col name: expected_value )

```
name_of_fruits, expected_value
apples|oranges, oranges
apples|bananas, bananas
apples, apples
apples|mango|pears, pears
```

I tried performing the below code:

```
select name_of_fruits, right((name_of_fruits),position('|' in reverse(name_of_fruits))-1) as expected_value from table
```

**I get an error SQL Error Invalid operation : Invalid length (context : Negative value given)**

Could anyone assist to pull the required values. Thanks

I am using Redshift DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    name_of_fruits,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(name_of_fruits, '.*|', '') AS expected_value
FROM yourTable;
```

The pattern `.*|` works nicely here, because in the case of a name string which does have more than one fruit, it would strip everything off leaving only the final fruit.  And, in the case of a name string having only one name, the replacement would just no-op, also leaving the same fruit name.